# DI configuration for multiple RabbitMQ exchanges and queues

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, rabbitmq

I'm trying to configure DI for EventBusRabbitMQ implementation. It works perfectly fine for a single exchange, queue..

```
 services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, EventBusRabbitMQ>(serviceProvider =>
 {
     ...

     return new EventBusRabbitMQ(connection, "exchange_EX1", "queue_Q1",..);
 });
```

and in the application configuration

```
var eventBus = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>();

eventBus.Subscribe<FooEvent, FooEventHandler>;
```

I want to register multiple implementations with different configurations of EventBusRabbitMQ so i can pick and choose which exchange and queue to target when i resolve for IEventBus.

What i don't want is to be explicit about the implementations since the only thing that differs is just the exchange and queue.

```
services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, EventBusRabbitMQ_EX1_Q1>
services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, EventBusRabbitMQ_EX2_Q2>
```

what alternates do i have?

Comment: have you a finite set of `EventBusRabbitMQ_EX1_Q1`  ?

Comment: yes, 3 - 5 different configurations per service

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution given you have a finit set of implementation is to consider a solution like this:

```
public interface  IEventBusRabbitMQ_EX1_Q1:IEventBus
{
}
public interface  IEventBusRabbitMQ_EX2_Q2:IEventBus
{
}
```

and then change your code to inject the right instance

```
services.AddSingleton<IEventBusRabbitMQ_EX1_Q1, EventBusRabbitMQ_EX1_Q1>
services.AddSingleton< IEventBusRabbitMQ_EX2_Q2, EventBusRabbitMQ_EX2_Q2>
```

But there is another solution which  is described [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface)

basically is an enricher kind pattern like but I don't recommend it because it reduces the readability of the code.